# How to call a method on objects?

Tags: c#

I have made an employee class and made a method which displays employee info. I made multiple employee objects and call the display method on each of them but the console only displays the first object. Here is my code:

```
 public class Employee
    {
        private string name { set ; get; }
        private int idNumber { set; get; }
        private String department { set; get; }
        private String position{ set; get; }
    //  public override string ToString()
    // {
    // return "Name: " + name + "\nID number: " + idNumber + "\nDepartment: " + department + "\nPosition: " + position;
    //  }


    public Employee(String name, int idNumber, String department, String position)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.idNumber = idNumber;
            this.department = department;
            this.position = position;
        }
        // Constructor: Name and ID # are parameters
        public Employee(String name, int idNumber)
        { // Constructor with name and ID as Param
            this.name = name;
            this.idNumber = idNumber;
            department = "";
            position = "";

        }
        // Constructor: No Parameter
        public Employee()
        {
            name = "";
            department = "";
            position = "";
            idNumber = 0;
        }


        public void DisplayAll()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name + "\nID number: " + idNumber + "\nDepartment: " + department + "\nPosition: " + position);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```

My main class:

```
class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee("John wick ", 23, "Health", "Doctor");
            Employee employee2 = new Employee("rober johnson ", 33, "Education", "Teacher");
            Employee jack = new Employee("Jack Freeman", 321);
            employee.DisplayAll();
            employee2.DisplayAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Expected outcome:Console will display employee information and will also dispaly employee1 information. I only see employee display information

Comment: Remove the `Console.ReadKey`, it's waiting for input.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `Console.ReadKey`, which makes the Console wait for user input.
You probably put it there to prevent the Console from closing instantly.
So  you want to move it outside of the `DisplayAll` method like so:

```
 public void DisplayAll()
 {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name + "\nID number: " + idNumber + "\nDepartment: " + department + "\nPosition: " + position);
        // Removed here
 }
```

And in your Mainclass:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee("John wick ", 23, "Health", "Doctor");
    Employee employee2 = new Employee("rober johnson ", 33, "Education", "Teacher");
    Employee jack = new Employee("Jack Freeman", 321);
    employee.DisplayAll();
    employee2.DisplayAll();

    // ... and put it here
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```